# Python pathlib: How to filter files from path with expression matching?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I would like to filter out files containing a certain expression within a directory. I'm quite new to Python. In R I would have worked with Strings, but in Python I worked with `pathlib`, which has some neat advantages such as cross-plattform compatibility.

E.g I have a list made of `WindowsPath` objects to filter:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import re, glob

fileDir = Path(r'T:\testdir')
filelist = [img for img in fileDir.iterdir() if img.is_file()]

print(filelist)
[WindowsPath('T:/testdir/T31TGL_20180108T104421_B11.jp2'), WindowsPath('T:/testdir/T31TGL_20180108T104421_B12.jp2'), WindowsPath('T:/testdir/T31TGL_20180108T104421_TCI.jp2')]
```

Desired output is the path to the file `T31TGL_20180108T104421_TCI.jp2`. E.g. I want to filter the files contained in `filelist` for the expression `TCI`.

I tried to filter using expression matching as follows:

```py
expr = re.compile('.*TCI')
TCI_path = list(filter(expr.match, imglist))
```

THis throws the error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

e.g. does not work with the WindowsPath objects of the `filelist`. I also tried with the `.glob` method (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html#glob.glob) but am too inexperienced with python to seem to get it to work...

How can I filter this list accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can convert your `WindowsPath`s to `str` before matching:

```
TCI_path = list(item for item in filelist if expr.match(str(item)))
```

---

`.glob("*TCI*")` (or maybe even `.glob("*_TCI.jp2")`) should also work...